# Resetting stack shows an older page in stack for a split second in react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I am in my SignIn screen and I reset my stack to point to the Main TabNavigator I see the Welcome screen briefly. It doesn't look appealing at all. How do I solve this?
I have the following code in my router:

```
export const WelcomeStack = StackNavigator({
welcome:{
    screen: WelcomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        header: () => { null }
    }
},
SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
        headerBackTitle: "Tilbake",
        headerTintColor: colors.background,
        headerStyle: {
            marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 24 : 0,
            backgroundColor: colors.primary
        },
        title: 'SeniorSmart'
    }
},
main: {
    screen: TabNavigator({
        FindEvents: {
            screen: FindEvents,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'Finn aktiviteter',
            },
        },
    }, {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
        swipeEnabled: false,
        animationEnabled: true
    }),
}
```

And this is the code I use to navigate to the main tabnavigator screen:

```
 const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
                        index: 0,
                        actions: [
                            NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'main' }),
                        ],
                    });
                    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```